# Entitlements / Capabilities per Xcode scheme

Tags: ios, xcode

The `Apple Pay` entitlement / capability is only valid in the App Store. I am releasing this app in both the App Store and Enterprise.

- If the `App Store Release` scheme is selected I'd like Xcode to enable the `Apple Pay` entitlement.
- If the `Enterprise Release` scheme selected I'd like Xcode to disable the `Apple Pay` entitlement.

Comment: Hey! Did you figure out a solution for this? We're facing the same issue.

Comment: @Sid No i haven't :-(, please let me know if you have.

Comment: If it helps, we had looked at our entitlements file and had a duplicate entry in there. We removed that and it fixed some of our issues. What we also went ahead and did is set up a separate entitlements file without Apple pay for enterprise builds :) Hope this helps

Comment: @volni Have you manage to find a way around this?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can achieve the desired behaviour by using a different build configuration.

1. Copy the entitlements file and adjust it to your needs, e.g, remove the Apple Pay entitlement for enterprise distribution
2. Select the project on the project settings view
3. Add a new build configuration, e.g., AppStore
   [image: Xcode project settings]
4. Switch to your app target and adjust the value for the new build configuration.
   [image: Target build settings]
5. Create a new scheme, e.g., AppStore and select the new build configuration in the "Archive" Section of the scheme settings
   [image: Scheme settings]

In general, it is a good idea to have separate schemes and build configurations. That way you can support several different build configurations depending on your needs, e.g., Enterprise distribution, Hockey Testing, App Store etc. .

If you want to make your project setup more maintainable consider using xcconfig files to organize your build settings.

Comment: But that doesn't help with App Capabilities.

Comment: @Ashraf Tawfeeq - Have you found any alternate solution for it?

Comment: Hi @GauravBorole  you can have a look at my solution to this.

Comment: Really neat way, especially when using extensions, this is the right way to do it. Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 2):

A possible approach:

1. Put your different schemes' entitlements files in a folder
2. Have your project or target's Build Settings > Code Signing Entitlements point to a location such as `$(PROJECT_DIR)/AppName/AppName.entitlements`
3. In Edit Scheme > Build > Pre-actions, add a "Run Script" action to copy the entitlements file for that scheme, to the location you specified in step 2. e.g. `cp ${PROJECT_DIR}/entitlements/DevScheme.entitlements ${PROJECT_DIR}/AppName/AppName.entitlements`

Answer (score 0):

I had done this for some time. My solution was based on git branches. I had four branches: `master`, `app-store`, `enterprise` and `feature`.

Among these, `app-store` and `enterprise` were derived from `master` with their own variations, and `feature` was for new features in development.

Every time I finished building a feature and QA people finished verifying it, I would merge it to `master` , then merge `master` to `app-store` and `enterprise`.

I'm not that proficient with git, but I managed to work smoothly.

---

I've checked other answers, and realize my solution is a little silly :).